# How to add HTML5 support to Wordpress theme

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Can someone please let me know how I can add HTML5 support to a Wordpress theme that was created pre-HTML5?  Specifically, I'm using the WP-Adapt Theme.  I understand I'm supposed to put this code somewhere in the functions.php file?

```
add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'comment-list', 'comment-form', 'search-form', 'gallery', 'caption' ) );
```

I know very little about coding, so I was hoping someone could tell me exactly what to enter where. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "HTML5 Support"?

Comment: Since we don't know anything about your Wordpress theme, you should ask the original author whether he can modify it. That modification can be as easy as changing the doctype, or be a more robust, cleaner version of the theme. Either way, the author or a friend of yours should modify it directly, since without additional information, every answer might only remove some needles of the metal haystack.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your comments here. I think what I'll need to do is look into this specific theme's files and work out the necessary code.  By HTML5 support, I was referring to making my site compliant w/HTML5 code. I'll try to delve deeper into the theme before furthering the discussion here. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Change the doctype in header.php to

```
<!doctype html>
```

and you may want to add https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/ for IE support and http://selectivizr.com/ for CSS3 support.

What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: I was originally trying to implement HTML5 support, including the latest caption support.  However, I think I'll need to delve into the theme a bit more on my own based on what Dai has mentioned above. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Use modernizer.js . This will enable HTML5 tags support.